# Alternativas desenvolvimento mobile - Java FX, Android, CodenameOne

Tags: android, mobile

Estou realizando uma pesquisa de alternativas para desenvolvimento mobile nativo com algumas ferramentas de mercado. Além das próprias ferramentas para desenvolvimento nativo das plataformas (iOS e Android, por exemplo), encontrei algumas ferramentas interessantes como:

1. [CodenameOne](http://www.codenameone.com/index.html)
2. [LWUIT](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html) precursor de codenameOne, no qual é baseado.

Também realizei uma breve pesquisa sobre `Java FX` para desenvolvimento mobile e não encontrei algo que possa ser utilizado além do `javaME`.

Existem mais algumas ferramentas para desenvolvimento mobile nativo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente o appery.io

Porque é uma boa opção:

- Usa as bibliotecas do jQuery, jQuery mobile e PhoneGap;
- Usa linguagem javascript para qualquer plataforma;
- Fácil de desenhar interfaces gráficas;
- Compila pelo próprio serviço apps para android e iOS;

Tenho usado com excelentes resultados.

Comment: Ola Raphael, então eu escrevo um script ele compila e gera um apk ? (caso seja android)

Comment: Não só isso... ele tem recursos de arrastar-esoltar para o layout, usa javascript, funciona com folha de estilos, e por meio da própria plataforma, compilar e gerar um apk (android) e ipa (iOS)... vale a pena você dar uma olhada